# Arduino mega ethernet Udp client randomly failing

Tags: arduino-mega, ethernet

I have a keyestudio board identical to the arduino mega 2560. I use the matching keyestudio ks0156 W5100 ethernet shield. My code uses the following library for ethernet `paulstoffregen/Ethernet@0.0.0-alpha+sha.9f41e8231b`

I have the following code (initialization and "loop" code):

```c
const int port_broadcast{27333};
char udp_packet_buffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE + 1];

const byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};

EthernetUDP udp;

void init_ethernet() {
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing Ethernet using DHCP");

    if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.");

      while (true) {
        delay(1);
      }
    }

    if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }

    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dns);
  } else {
    Serial.print("DHCP assigned IP ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }

  udp.begin(port_broadcast);
}

void update_time() {
  int packet_size = udp.parsePacket();
  if (packet_size > 0) {
     const auto num_read = udp.read(udp_packet_buffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
    Serial.print("Received ");
    Serial.print(num_read);
    Serial.println(" bytes: ");
    if(num_read > 0) {
      udp_packet_buffer[num_read] = '\0';
      Serial.println(udp_packet_buffer);
    }
  }
}
```

On my Windows device in the same network I have a service that every 2 seconds posts the current time in the format `2021-09-19 15:37:30` over UDP broadcast to my local network. This works quite well until suddenly the board starts receiving wrong values. Here is a sample output from the board:

```
DHCP assigned IP 192.168.1.120
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:37
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:39
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:41
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:43
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:45
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:47
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:49
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:51
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:53
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:55
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:57
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 19:59:59
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:01
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:03
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:05
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:07
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:09
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:11
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:13
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:15
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:17
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:19
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:21
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 2
Received 19 bytes: 
␒0"1    0
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-19 20:00:␒7
Received 19 bytes: 
2021-09-1        ␒0
Received 3 bytes: 
2
Received 24 bytes: 
20:00␚3!␁B��
```

As you can see suddenly the output makes no sense anymore. There is no sensor attached, no input happening or anything else going on, it just randomly starts outputing wrong values. Also when it starts outputing wrong values it does not continue for long before completely stopping to receive anythin alltogether. According to Wireshark the windows service keeps posting the right data, so I can rule out that it has something to do with the service.

So my question is, why would my board suddenly stop receiving data over UDP without any apparent reason or interaction from the outside? Reseting the board will immediately continue to print more data, but until then it stopped. It got adequate power supply and the LAN cable is very short. Am I doing something wrong in my code? Does it look like an issue with the Ethernet shield?

For completeness sake this is the C# code from the service that is sending to the UDP broadcast:

```cs
        private UdpClient _time_broadcaster;
        private readonly IPEndPoint _broadcast = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255"), 27333);

        private void timer_elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs args) {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var year = now.Year;
            var month = now.Month;
            var day = now.Day;

            var hour = now.Hour;
            var minute = now.Minute;
            var second = now.Second;

            var result = $"{year:D4}-{month:D2}-{day:D2} {hour:D2}:{minute:D2}:{second:D2}";
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);
            _time_broadcaster.Send(data, data.Length, _broadcast);
        }
```

Comment: seems like a buffer is getting cumulatively overfilled ... possibly by not retrieving all data from buffer at each read .... does the program always fail at the same location?

Comment: Yea, I thought something similar too, so I also checked that and sometimes it fails after a few seconds, sometimes after a minute, sometimes even more. What did make a change is changing the windows service to send to 192.168.1.120 (the assigned IP) instead of 192.168.1.255 (broadcast), it has been running for 30 minutes now without any interruption. I need to do some more testing there.

Comment: that probably eliminates the buffer overflow idea ... possible bug in the library

Comment: does not necessarily eliminate overflow- depends on what you are listening for.  it may also be a feature related to monitoring network traffic between other devices rather than a bug.  try reverting to old settings and having network of only 2 devices.

Comment: did you try the Ethernet library from Library Manager?

Comment: I am using PlatformIO, I will check out which one is the official one from Library Manager in Arduino IDE and try to find that one in PIO.